# No SonarQube analysis for dotnet Core projects because of duplicate ProjectGuid

Tags: .net-core, tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

My Sonarqube analysis of a dotnet core solution in TFS2017 fails, because of 'duplicate project guids'.
This is undoubtedly because dotnet core projects do not have a project guid. However I cannot make Sonarqube understand that I doesn't have to search for a project guid.
How do I correct this problem?

Here is the logging from the TFS build process:

```
 2018-08-30T09:31:42.5330000Z C:\Build2017\1\s\XXXXYYYYY\BRRRRRRMessageReciever.csproj, C:\Build2017\1\s\AdaFrontend\AdaFrontend.csproj, C:\Build2017\1\s\XXXXYYYYY\BRRRRRRMessageReciever.csproj, C:\Build2017\1\s\XXXXYYYYY\BRRRRRRMessageReciever.csproj, C:\Build2017\1\s\RRRRTester\BRRRRRRMessageRecieverTester.csproj
2018-08-30T09:31:42.5840000Z WARNING: Duplicate ProjectGuid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: "C:\Build2017\1\s\XXXXYYYYY\BRRRRRRMessageReciever.csproj"
2018-08-30T09:31:42.5850000Z WARNING: Duplicate ProjectGuid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: "C:\Build2017\1\s\AdaFrontend\AdaFrontend.csproj"
2018-08-30T09:31:42.5860000Z WARNING: Duplicate ProjectGuid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". The project will not be analyzed by SonarQube. Project file: "C:\Build2017\1\s\RRRRTester\BRRRRRRMessageRecieverTester.csproj"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add one. The [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) is not very clear about this:

> Single .NET Core project files (csproj or vbproj) will not be analyzed unless a unique guid element is added in the csproj or vbproj file. If the project is part of a solution, the  element is not required.

But see the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056816/sonarcloud-with-vsts-has-error-duplicate-projectguid-00000000-0000-0000-0000-0) SO question that refers to the same error using SonarCloud (that product has the same code base as SonarQube). On [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/TtMoLTSvmdQ) forum and [this](http://mrshipley.com/2018/03/21/static-analysis-for-net-core-projects-using-sonarqube/) blog the same advice is given.